# AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, admob

I am integrating Unity admob in my unity game which is build in Unity 2018.1.1f1 and i am using following.

- Unity 2018.1.1f1
- Admob plugin v 3.15.1
- JDK 8
- SDK Lollipop
- Google play services [latest]

and getting the following error in logcat. while i have try Android resolver version but its not fix it while if select force Android resolver version than i get gradle failed to fetch dependencies message.

```
 AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:326)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$2.queueIdle(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:392)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.HSquare.PaintIt-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.HSquare.PaintIt-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.HSquare.PaintIt-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error seems your com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds Plugin not found in your apk.

Makesure your Unity project's Android plugin folder contains all necessary files imported for Admob plugin.

Answer (score 3):

In unity editor, Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android Resolver > Force Resolve

This will download the miss libraries.

Comment: Thanks, it works clearly now. But i didn't see any ads. I'm not sure about it. But game is work properly.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using ProGuard, make sure to set a custom proguard file. For me what worked was this:

```
-keep class com.google.unity.** {
   *;
}
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.**{
   public *;
}
-keep public class com.google.ads.**{
   public *;
}
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontobfuscate
```

As shown [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/2458).

I'm not sure if "dontobfuscate" would be applied for the whole app though, seems like it might, and I haven't tested it without it.